# Trace of logarithm of anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Is it true in general that the trace of log of an anti-diagonal matrix equals to the sum of log of anti diagonal elements? For a definite example, I have encountered a problem in which I need to compute
Trace[Log[M(p,q)]], where M(p,q) is a some function of the form $$M(p,q) =  \eta(p) \delta(p+q) $$
Is it correct that the value of the above expression if $$\int dq \: \eta(q) \: \delta (0)$$ up to some constant?
I have checked this for a few finite dimensional matrices on Mathematica and found it to be true:

```
  $Assumptions = 
  And[a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0, f > 0, g > 0, h > 0];
  mat = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, b, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, c, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, d, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, e, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, g, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {h, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

 Tr[MatrixLog[mat]] // FullSimplify
```

The answer is

```
4 I \[Pi] + Log[a b c d e f g h]
```

(same was true for some higher dimensions too. The constant $4 i \pi$ is inconsequential for my purpose)

I was wondering if it is true in general and can it be proved to be so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true: the trace of $\log M$ in your setting is the sum of logarithms of antidiagonal values, up to an integer multiple of $\pi i$.

Matrix logarithm are a bit complicated due to non-uniqueness, so it's easier to think of matrix exponential instead. One of the [fundamental properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_determinant_of_the_matrix_exponential) of the matrix exponential is
$$\det (e^A) = e^{\operatorname{tr}A}$$
Here $e^A=M$ is your matrix and $A$ is (any) matrix logarithm of $M$. The determinant of $M$ is the product of antidiagonal entries up to the sign, the sign being $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$. And the trace of $A$ is a logarithm of that; recall that the logarithm is defined up to an even multiple of $\pi i$. Thus,
$$
\operatorname{tr}A = \sum_{k=1}^n \log a_k \pmod {\pi i}
$$